# public org.demo.ComplaintQueryObject org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication$ComplaintAPI.find(java.lang.String) mapped

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, axon

I am developing **Spring Boot + Axon + CQRS** example. In this example, while starting the main method, I get the below error.

Looks like String cant be used in place of the ID. I tried to convert String to ID but it doesn't worked well.

Could you please guide me what should be done ? Here is the my whole source code.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'demoComplaintsApplication.ComplaintAPI' method 
public java.util.List<org.demo.ComplaintQueryObject> org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication$ComplaintAPI.findAll()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'demoComplaintsApplication.ComplaintAPI' bean method
public org.demo.ComplaintQueryObject org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication$ComplaintAPI.find(java.lang.String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication.main(DemoComplaintsApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'demoComplaintsApplication.ComplaintAPI' method 
public java.util.List<org.demo.ComplaintQueryObject> org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication$ComplaintAPI.findAll()
to {[],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'demoComplaintsApplication.ComplaintAPI' bean method
public org.demo.ComplaintQueryObject org.demo.DemoComplaintsApplication$ComplaintAPI.find(java.lang.String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:581) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:545) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:267) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:252) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:250) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:189) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Code:

```
package org.demo;

import static org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateLifecycle.apply;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import static org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateLifecycle.apply;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGateway;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoComplaintsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoComplaintsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public static class ComplaintAPI {

        private final ComplaintQueryObjectRepository repostory;
        private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

        public ComplaintAPI(ComplaintQueryObjectRepository repostory, CommandGateway commandGateway) {
            this.repostory = repostory;
            this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
        }

        @PostMapping
        public CompletableFuture<Object> fileCompplaint(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request) {
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            return commandGateway
                    .send(new FileComplaintCommand(id, request.get("company"), request.get("description")));
        }

        @GetMapping
        public List<ComplaintQueryObject> findAll() {
            return repostory.findAll();
        }

        @GetMapping
        public ComplaintQueryObject find(@PathVariable String id) {
            return repostory.findById(id).get();
        }
    }

    @Aggregate
    public static class Complaint {
        @AggregateIdentifier
        private String complaintId;

        public Complaint() {
            super();
        }

        @CommandHandler
        public Complaint(FileComplaintCommand command) {
            Assert.hasLength(command.getCompany());

            apply(new ComplaintFileEvent(command.getId(), command.getCompany(), command.getDescription()));
        }

        @EventSourcingHandler
        public void on(ComplaintFileEvent event) {
            this.complaintId = event.getId();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class ComplaintQueryObjectUpdater {

        private final ComplaintQueryObjectRepository repository;

        public ComplaintQueryObjectUpdater(ComplaintQueryObjectRepository repository) {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void on(ComplaintFileEvent event) {
            repository.save(new ComplaintQueryObject(event.getId(), event.getCompany(), event.getDescription()));
        }
    }

    public static class FileComplaintCommand {
        private String id;
        private String company;
        private String description;

        public FileComplaintCommand(String id, String company, String description) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.company = company;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to ambiguity that means you have multiple method with the same mappings.Change the second method by specifying path variable `@GetMapping("/{id}")`

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ComplaintQueryObject find(@PathVariable String id) {
     return repostory.findById(id).get();
}
```